# Better way to say "can be written in terms of"

Tags: soft-question

Suppose some expression $f$ can be written in terms of some variable $x$. What is a better way to express this?

We can say $f = A(x)$ where $A$ is some function of $f$; however, I'm not sure if this is an appropriate way to say this.

Comment: This question is a bit vague as it's currently written. Can you give an example or two to show what you mean by "some expression $f$ [...]"?

Answer (score 1):

You can say, $f=f(x)$. You can say, $f$ depends on $x$. You can say, $f$ is a function of $x$.